# Validate if User/Request is authenticated .net core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have implemented cookie authentication together with Novel ldap authentication in my .net core application.
I have a login screen where the users enters their credentials and once authenticated it redirects them to Home page. On my Login layout page I want to have a logout link which logouts the user out of the application. Earlier in my .net mvc application I could do:

```
 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
 {
   <li><a href="#">Hello, @ViewData["FullName"] !</a></li>
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Account")">Log Out</a></li>
 }
 else
 {
   <li><a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">Log In</a></li>
 }
```

All my authentication, redirects etc work fine but whats the equivalent of Request.IsAuthenticated in .net core or how can I check if the user is authenticated and show links etc accordingly.

Would appreciate inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What svek shared above should work. Debug to see if you are authenticating properly, you are setting up your cookies fine.

Specifically for .net core this should work.

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
   <a asp-area="" asp-controller="YouController" asp-action="YourAction">Logout</a>
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: this does not work. Does not throw any errors but simply does not show the logout link.

Comment: This works after the user is authenticated, which makes it pretty useless.  When your token cache has valid tokens, it incorrectly tells you that you're not authenticated.